# Toggling whether rows are displayed, subject to filter

Tags: tablesorter

First off, thanks mottie for doing so much in terms of answering questions and providing demos, it's been great. I have a table with drop-down filters using the widget. There is an option for one of the drop-down selectors, called "Deprecated". I am trying to use a button external to the table to toggle whether or not any rows with this "Deprecated" value are being displayed. When these rows are being shown, I want them to behave like all other table rows.

I couldn't find a straightforward way to do this, after approaching it at several different angles. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: To help people help you answer your question, you should include code samples indicating what you have tried and where your code fails. You'd save people a lot of time if you told them which "several different angles" you used to approach the issue so that they won't suggest things that you've already tried.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16375042/145346) and see if the "concept" of moving deprecated rows into another (hidden) tbody would work better for you.

Comment: @Mottie Thanks, I didn't have any code to show before because all my approaches were bad and I scrapped them. I almost have this working with the method you suggested, I'm just stuck on making the hidden rows stay hidden when sorting is applied (it seems to actually only happen if you sort before using the button). [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/3142/)

Comment: [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/3146/) Simple fix

Comment: Awesome! Add that as an answer and I'll upvote it :P